# Get value from Angular 4.5 component in template

Tags: angular, angular-services

I am working on Angular 4.5, within I have self contain folder with its component, template and service. I have method Injectable service

### Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
 export class MsalService
{
   getProduct(): string
   {
      return "12 Apples";
   }
 }
```

and component where I am intended to call this service and print value from getProduct() into template as;

### Login Component

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import { Location} from '@angular/common';
 import { MsalService } from '../Services/msal.service';

 @Component({
  selector: 'auth-login',
  templateUrl: './Login.Template.html',
  styleUrls: ['./Login.Style.scss'], 
  providers: [MsalService]
 })

  export class Login{

    constructor( private msalService: MsalService){
  }

  public pageTitle: string = "testing .....";

  getService() : void{
      this.msalService.getProduct();
  }

}
```

template where I am trying to call method from login component and print value in template when click event happened

### Login Template

```
<div class="panel-heading">
     {{pageTitle}}
</div>

<a class="btn btn-link"  (click)="getService()">Login</a>
```

finally I need to call this whole function in another component as;

### another module

```
import { Login } from '../security/login/login.component';

@NgModule({
imports: [
 Login
  ]
})

 export class LayoutModule {
}
```

another template where I want to use login method to call which is separate complete function and for simple, print value from method

```
getService() : void{
          this.msalService.getProduct();
```

---

```
 <p><auth-login></auth-login></p>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. I can only say that calling a method that gets some string value out of a service and does nothing with the result doesn't make much sense. If you want to print the string returned by the service, you need to have {{ getService() }} in your template, and getService() needs to return the string, not return void.

Comment: I trying to simple implementation before configure login service. so I have security component within I have login component and template which suppose to have login / logout button... this is self contain complete partial function which is then I am calling this whole login function from security in layout component

Comment: Please, ask a question about the code you posted. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: print  getService() : void{
        this.msalService.getProduct();
    } value into template that is 12 Apples

Comment: I think this   `getService() {
    return  this.msalService.getProduct()  }` This is all you need . to get the value

Comment: thanks it work... one milestone done...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you need to print the value.

```
 getService(){
   return this.msalService.getProduct();
 }
```

or Else

```
yourProperty:string;

getService() : void{
      yourProperty = this.msalService.getProduct();
  }
```

Template

```
<html>
<p>{{ getService() }}</p>
</html>


<html>
 <p>{{ yourProperty }}</p>
</html>
```

Comment: This is same what @JB Nizel was talking about. Your question is little vague. I

Answer (score 0):

this is how I print component method return value in template.

```
getService() : string{
       return this.msalService.getProduct();
  }
```